# Session Cookie not overwriting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net MVC project that when someone visits the home page it presents a number of buttons depending on which departments they work for.
They can then select the department they want to log in under.

The following controller then sets a session cookie with the appropriate contractId.

However if they login again under a different department the cookie doesn't get overwritten with the new contractId

```
        public ActionResult SetContractId(int contractId)
    {

        Session["LoggedContractId"] = contractId;

        return RedirectToAction("IndexLoggedIn");
    }
```

I call the above from the buttons which are displayed in the view using the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: 25px">
    @Html.ActionLink("Login under this Contract", "SetContractId", new { contractId = item.ContractId }, new { @Class = "btn btn-primary" }) <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentName)</b>
</div>

}
```

I use this cookie value to set up the system for them. I use the session variable like this:

```
 public ActionResult StartDebrief()
    {
        if (Session["LoggedContractId"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("IndexLogin", "Home", null);
        }
        else
        {
            var user = User.Identity.Name;
            string userName = user.Substring(7);
            var creator = Peopledb.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == userName);
            var creatorContractId = (int)Session["LoggedContractId"];

            //Use creatorContractId in the viewmodel and other areas

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `However if they login again under a different department` What do you mean by this?

Comment: They are presented with several buttons, one for each department they work for.

Comment: Just for clarification: session data aren't cookies. The cookie on the user machine holds a key and the contract ID is held in-memory on the server for that user. So making a change to the contract ID will not change the cookie (same key)

Comment: @LennartStoop thanks, how would I go about changing it then? It works setting it first time because I access the contractId and use it.

Comment: Hard to say, the code you posted looks fine. Can you add a breakpoint to the line where you change the session data in  `SetContractId ` and verify its called?

Comment: @LennartStoop yes its calling it

Comment: Ok perhaps you can add the code that evaluates the contract id?

Comment: @LennartStoop Added the code I use to pick up on the session variable.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong tbh. So if you put a breakpoint in both methods: the session data is set correctly in the first method `SetContractId` and then is reverted back to the old value in the second method `StartDebrief`?

Comment: @LennartStoop Thanks I discovered the error further on in the code where I handle the session data. Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score -1):

Your code to update the session information looks good in my opinion. This means that the session data should be updated correctly. However, it is possible the call to this function is not rightly in place. Try debugging the function SetContractId(). Where do you call this function, after a new login?

Comment: I call it using an action link on the button, I've updated the post to show the code I use in the view.

Comment: Answers are not for asking for clarification.